# Relating $N$ to $\epsilon$ to justify $\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty}\frac{n}{2n +\sqrt{n+1}}$

Tags: real-analysis

> Find and justify $\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} S_n$ using definition of converge/divergence of sequence
>   $$ S_n = \frac{n}{2n +\sqrt{n+1}}$$

$$\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} S_n =\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{n}{2n +\sqrt{n+1}}$$

Applying l'hospital rule
$$\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} S_n =  \frac{ \lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty}(n)'}{ \lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty}(2n +\sqrt{n+1})'}= \frac{1}{2+\frac{1}{2}(n+1)^{-1/2}}= \frac{1}{2}$$

Let's check that $\forall \epsilon >0 $, there exists an integer such that:
$$ |S_n - \frac{1}{2} | =  |\frac{n}{2n +\sqrt{n+1}} - \frac{1}{2}| = 
\frac{\sqrt{n+1}}{4n+2\sqrt{n+1}}< \epsilon$$

if $$n \geq N$$

How do you proceed in such problem to relate $N$ to $\epsilon$?

Comment: Hint: divide through by $\frac{n}{n}$, and bound based on the resulting denominator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider that for $n\geq 1$, $$\sqrt{n+1}\leq 2\sqrt{n}$$ Therefore, $$\frac{\sqrt{n+1}}{4n+\sqrt{n+1}}\leq \frac{\sqrt{n+1}}{4n}\leq \frac{\sqrt{n}}{2n} = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{n}}$$ Therefore, for any $\epsilon > 0$, if $n\geq N > \frac{1}{4\epsilon^2}$ (which we get by solving $\frac{1}{2\sqrt{N}} < \epsilon$), then $$\frac{\sqrt{n+1}}{4n+\sqrt{n+1}} < \epsilon$$

Comment: dang, beat me to it by a couple seconds :) +1

Comment: Sorry ;) I'm on mobile, too.

Comment: Haha, then you definitely deserve the rep! I must be off my game today

Comment: @MichaelLee I did over my initial computationsit seems it should have a negative sign such as $-
\frac{\sqrt{n+1}}{4n+2\sqrt{n+1}}$ am i doing a mistake? if not does it constitute a problem with $\epsilon>0$?

Comment: No, it shouldn't have a negative sign. If you add the negative sign, then the function becomes strictly _negative_, which is impossible because you took the absolute value of it. You had it correct before.